# Secondary monitor working, laptop screen black

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I've been using a dock for my laptop for some time now and it has always worked fine, but now my laptop screen stays black, with the secondary dock monitor working just fine. I have a dual boot with Windows and on there the screen works just fine. With `nomodeset` the laptop screen does turn on, but then the secondary monitor doesn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on the HP EliteBook 840 G5 3JX27EA. My laptop has Intel graphics. Not sure what info is relevant here but I'd be happy to provide anything else.

Output of `xrandr` without `nomodeset`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1412, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+332 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output with `nomodeset`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Comment: Add output of `xrandr`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio added

Comment: Please do the same when you use `nomodeset`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio added too!

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in with Wayland ?

Comment: @mondotofu doesn't change anything.